# Unhandled Exception In HttpClient web api call in asp.net core but couldn't understand the issue

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-3.0, dotnet-httpclient, webapi

In postman I issue a request with the following body against `http://localhost:2001/api/ProductQuality/Check`:

```json
{
    "productid": "2274",
    "productcorenumber": "1321",
    "value": "AE1C1F-0363-D6F-B3D-AE0029A8",
    "contacts": [
        15998,
        1012
    ],
    "ispassed": "0",
    "isok": "0",
    "isgood": "false"
}
```

and this will come to  here(I have one method in my controller)

```cs
[HttpPost("api/ProductQuality/Check")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Check([FromBody] CheckInput input)
{
    var result = await _Checker.Checkercall(input);
}
```

in `Checkercall` implementation I am calling another API(as of now calling the same for testing purposes)

```cs
public async Task<QualityCheckResults> Checkercall(CheckInput input)
{
    QualityCheckResults QualityCheckInputResult = new QualityCheckResults();
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:2001/api/ProductQuality/Check", content))
        //hope i have to give https here
        {
            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            QualityCheckInputResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QualityCheckResults>(apiResponse);
        }
    }
    return QualityCheckInputResult;
}
```

I am getting Unhandled Exception here but I couldn't understand the issue.

Comment: From what I understand, you are doing recursive API call without an exit condition? You'll get out of memory exception and/or thread starvation because there is no exit condition

Comment: is that the problem causing my exception.Am new to this so i wonder how i can fix this

Comment: I can't tell without information like the exception details or call stack. Your API business logic should not be calling the API itself, even for testing. This leads to recursion. Instead you could implement a different API (e.g. /api/ProductQuality/Check/mock) which imitates the behavior of the real external API for testing purposes and call it instead.

Comment: Could not cast or convert from System.String to .NetCore.Core.Models.Response.CheckResults.

Comment: You should look at `ADOCheckerAsync.cs` line 52. You are getting a deserialization error here. My guess is that you are trying to deserialize a JSON string into a .NET object (a `CheckResults` instance)

Comment: i shouldnt do like that?

Comment: No. You can deserialize a JSON object into .NET object, but without custom JSON conversion logic, you cannot deserialize a JSON string into .NET object by default

Comment: and when i debug in the response (before coming to deserialzation) i am getting the bad request error

Comment: Because input JSON serialization errors are treated as model state errors by the framework which results in 400 response. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#automatic-http-400-responses)

Comment: i just want to return the responses(a json obj) by this httpclient call,but i am unable to find a solution